# Check if elements from a Dataframe column are in another Pandas dataframe row and append to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame like this:

| Casa | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Solo Deportes | Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL |
| Solo Deportes | Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin... |
| Solo Deportes | Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu |
| Solo Deportes | Remera Michael Jordan Chicago Bulls |

and `Df2`:

| Palabra | Marca |
| --- | --- |
| Acqualine | Acqualine |
| Addnice | Addnice |
| Adnnice | Addnice |
| Under Armour | Under Armour |
| Jordan | Nike |
| Adidas | Adidas |
| Reebok | Reebok |

How can I check each row of `df['Name']`, see if the row contains a value of `Df2['Palabra']`, and in that case get the value of `Df2['Marca']` and put it in the new column?. The result should be something like this:

| Casa | Name | Marca |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Solo Deportes | Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL | Adidas |
| Solo Deportes | Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin... | Under Armour |
| Solo Deportes | Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu | Reebok |
| Solo Deportes | Remera Michael Jordan Chicago Bulls | Nike |

**Data:**

`df`:

```
{'Casa': ['Solo Deportes', 'Solo Deportes', 'Solo Deportes', 'Solo Deportes'],
 'Name': ['Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL',
          'Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin...',
          'Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu',
          'Remera Michael Jordan Chicago Bulls']}
```

`Df2`:

```
{'Palabra': ['Acqualine', 'Addnice', 'Adnnice', 'Under Armour', 'Jordan', 'Adidas', 'Reebok'], 
 'Marca': ['Acqualine', 'Addnice', 'Addnice', 'Under Armour', 'Nike', 'Adidas', 'Reebok']}
```

Comment: Done!!! Thanks!!!!.... Real Df2 has 300 rows...the idea is to loop Df1['Name'], see if contains some value of Df2['Palabra'] and in that case get the value in  Df2['Marca']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `iterrows` in a generator expression and `next` to iterate over `Df2` and check if a matching item appears:

```
df1['Marca'] = df1['Name'].apply(lambda name: next((r['Marca'] for _, r in Df2.iterrows() if r['Palabra'] in name), float('nan')))
```

Output:

```
            Casa                                               Name         Marca
0  Solo Deportes              Paleta De Padel Adidas Metalbone CTRL        Adidas
1  Solo Deportes  Zapatillas Running Under Armour Charged Stamin...  Under Armour
2  Solo Deportes           Rompeviento Con Capucha Reebok Woven Azu        Reebok
3  Solo Deportes                Remera Michael Jordan Chicago Bulls          Nike
```